# C# Canny Edge Square Detect

Tags: c#, object-detection, camera-calibration, square

I filmed a chessboard

I know the actual length of one of the rectangles on this chessboard

Canny Edge was used to detect the outline of a square

But I can't find a square

Find as many squares as you can and tell me how to paint them red

Please help me.
**Method1**

```
public Mat NewFilterTest(Mat InputMat) 
{ 
    if (InputMat == null) return InputMat; 
    Mat OutputMat = InputMat.Clone();
    Mat GrayMat = new Mat();
    Cv2.CvtColor(InputMat, GrayMat, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
        
    // 캐니 엣지 필터로 가장자리 검출 : Canny Edge Apply
    Mat EdgeMat = new Mat();
    Cv2.Canny(GrayMat, EdgeMat, tbar\[2\].Value, tbar\[3\].Value, 3, true);
    Mat imsicanny = new Mat();
    Cv2.Resize(EdgeMat, imsicanny, new OpenCvSharp.Size(0, 0), 0.5, 0.5);
   Cv2.ImShow("canny111", imsicanny);
    FindContours2(EdgeMat, OutputMat);
    return OutputMat;
}
```

**Method2**

```
private void FindContours2(Mat InputMat, Mat OutputMat)
{
    OpenCvSharp.Point[][] contours;
    HierarchyIndex[] hierarchy;
    InputMat.FindContours(out contours, out hierarchy, RetrievalModes.List, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxSimple);
    foreach (var cnt in contours)
    {
        var epsilon = 0.02 * Cv2.ArcLength(cnt, true);
        var approx = Cv2.ApproxPolyDP(cnt, epsilon, true);
        var approxPoints = approx.OfType< IEnumerable<OpenCvSharp.Point>>();
    
        if (approx.Length == 4 && approx.All(x => Math.Abs(x.X - approx[0].X) == 0 || Math.Abs(x.Y - approx[0].Y) == 0))
        {
            OutputMat.DrawContours(approxPoints, -1, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**
[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHQsW.jpg)